# Determination of stixt(2)`s fontencoding and fontfamily

Tags: fonts, stix

I would like to use symbol ≙ which I found as no. 2259 in stixt(2). How can I determine its `\fontencoding` and `\fontfamily`? Do I need to change anything else in my code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\wedgeq{\stackrel{\wedge}{=}}

\usepackage{iftex}
\ifLuaTeX \renewcommand\wedgeq{{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}\selectfont≙}}% stix2 otf, 2259
\fi
\ifXeTeX  \renewcommand\wedgeq{{\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{STIXTwoMath-Regular.otf}\selectfont≙}}% stix2 otf, 2259
\fi
\ifPDFTeX \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
          \renewcommand\wedgeq{\fontencoding{T1}\fontfamily{which font .tfn}\selectfont≙}}% sitx2 tfn
\fi

\begin{document}
$a \wedgeq b$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Math characters are not accessed using `\selectfont`, that is for text. do you just want that character or simply use `stix2` package for pdftex or `unicode-math` for luatex/xetex which would define that character and set up stx2 generally?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I just want that one character and do not want to change the font of anything else.

Comment: second half of my answer then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the character for Unicode and classic tex as part of a general setup for Stix2 as follows

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\else
  \usepackage{stix2}
\fi

\begin{document}

$ a \wedgeq b$

\end{document}
```

If you just want the single character then `unicode-math` defines it as

```
\UnicodeMathSymbol{"02259}{\wedgeq}{\mathrel}{corresponds to (wedge, equals)}%
```

and `stix2.sty` defines it as

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{integrals}     {LS2}{stix2cal}  {m} {n}
\stix@MathSymbol{\wedgeq}                   {\mathrel}{integrals}{"8A}
```

so...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{iftex}

\iftutex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
  \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}[range={\wedgeq}]
\else
  \DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
  \DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}
  \DeclareSymbolFont{integrals}     {LS2}{stix2cal}  {m} {n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\wedgeq}  {\mathrel}{integrals}{"8A}
\fi

\begin{document}

$ a \wedgeq b$

\end{document}
```

So the direct answer to the "which font encoding and family?" question is

encoding `LS2` and family `stix2cal`.